# PostgreSQL Database Partitioning not working as I expect

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a table which includes Ip Location database. Here is the structure.

[image: Structure]

```
Here is create script;

-- public."IpLocation" definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public."IpLocation";

CREATE TABLE public."IpLocation" (
    "Id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"IpLocation_Id_seq"'::regclass),
    "IpFrom" float8 NOT NULL,
    "IpTo" float8 NOT NULL,
    "CountryCode" text NULL,
    "CountryName" text NULL,
    "RegionName" text NULL,
    "CityName" text NULL,
    "CreatedAt" timestamp NULL,
    "DeletedAt" timestamp NULL,
    "UpdatedAt" timestamp NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "IpLocation_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id","IpFrom")
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("IpFrom");
CREATE INDEX "IX_IpLocation_IpFrom" ON public."IpLocation" ("IpFrom");
CREATE INDEX "IX_IpLocation_IpFrom_IpTo" ON public."IpLocation" ("IpFrom","IpFrom");
CREATE INDEX "IX_IpLocation_IpTo" ON public."IpLocation" ("IpFrom");

-- public."IpLocation" foreign keys
```

I have 3.045.203 of records in this table. Some queries was running slow. Thats why I decided to partition table.

Here is my sql for partitioning;

```
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" default;
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition1 PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" FOR VALUES  from (-1) to (751619277);
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition2 PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" FOR VALUES  from (751619278) to (1503238554);
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition3 PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" FOR VALUES  from (1503238555) to (2254857831);
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition4 PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" FOR VALUES  from (2254857832) to (3006477108);
CREATE TABLE public.iplocationpartition5 PARTITION OF public."IpLocation" FOR VALUES  from (3006477109) to (MAXVALUE);
```

But when I run this Query getting the result below

```
EXPLAIN analyse select * from "IpLocation" where "IpFrom"<=1503395841 and "IpTo">=1503395841 limit 1;
```

---

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..204.15 rows=1 width=107) (actual time=125.634..125.636 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..34705.86 rows=170 width=107) (actual time=125.633..125.634 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Seq Scan on iplocationpartition1  (cost=0.00..9093.47 rows=33 width=83) (actual time=32.500..32.500 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (("IpFrom" <= '1503395841'::double precision) AND ("IpTo" >= '1503395841'::double precision))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 325098
        ->  Seq Scan on iplocationpartition2  (cost=0.00..25587.10 rows=92 width=83) (actual time=93.117..93.117 rows=0 loops=1)
              Filter: (("IpFrom" <= '1503395841'::double precision) AND ("IpTo" >= '1503395841'::double precision))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 915340
        ->  Index Scan using "iplocationpartition3_IpFrom_idx1" on iplocationpartition3  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=80) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ("IpFrom" <= '1503395841'::double precision)
              Filter: ("IpTo" >= '1503395841'::double precision)
        ->  Seq Scan on iplocationpartition  (cost=0.00..16.00 rows=44 width=172) (never executed)
              Filter: (("IpFrom" <= '1503395841'::double precision) AND ("IpTo" >= '1503395841'::double precision))
Planning Time: 0.301 ms
Execution Time: 125.663 ms
```

I'm running the same query with same data but not partitioned table.

```
EXPLAIN analyse select * from "IpLocationF" where "IpFrom"<=1503395841 and "IpTo">=1503395841 limit 1;
```

---

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.11 rows=1 width=82) (actual time=0.081..0.082 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on "IpLocationF"  (cost=0.00..84328.04 rows=738534 width=82) (actual time=0.081..0.081 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: (("IpFrom" <= '1503395841'::double precision) AND ("IpTo" >= '1503395841'::double precision))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 747
Planning Time: 0.087 ms
Execution Time: 0.094 ms
```

As you see non-partitioned table is faster.

How it can happen? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Partitioning never has increased the performance, what ever gave you that impression

Comment: @nbk, then why people do partitioning?

Comment: Partitioning is primarily used to be able to get rid of rows efficiently (e.g. drop a complete partition). It is only a performance tool if every query (or every query where speed matters) includes an equality condition on the partition key (e.g. `where part_key = ..`) or if the condition selects exactly one partition. Range conditions are not a good fit for partitioning. And for a small table like that partitioning isn't really needed to begin with.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `IpFrom` is supposed to be an IP address then isn't that defined as `inet` rather than `double precision` (if you want to store a numeric value, then `bigint` seems to be a better choice anyway

Comment: @fobus what is your PostgreSQL version? Since PG11 there is a parameter [enable_partition_pruning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITION-PRUNING). The setting controls planners ability to remove irrelevant partitions from the plan.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis yes, I have tried to run with set enable_partition_pruning=on; but no help.

Comment: @fobus please insert create script for your public."IpLocation" table.

Comment: Just noticed you searching if specific IP is in range of IP's. Thats why postgresql cant filter the tables to look from. Maybe you would be better off using single table like a_horse_with_no_name suggested and gin index on range made from IpFrom and IpTo. (Noticed that your select on IpLocationF uses sequential scan). There is no double range, but you could use int8range I guess...

Comment: @fobus do you have a limit how wide Ip range be? If so you could add upper and lower condition on ipStart  field (if it is the field you partition on)  and  expect partition prunning to do its job. I'm not sure if that will help - just a guess.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis This table includes world wide IP's, there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

How can it happen?  Dumb luck.  Your query on the unpartitioned table finds the row it is looking for after searching only 747 rows, and can then stop because of the LIMIT 1.  There is no explanation (that you have shared with us) for why it should be this way.  So it just seems to be luck.

The partitioned table didn't get so lucky.  But searching for different parameters will show different levels of luck.

You could vastly improve the partitioned table case by adding an index on "IpTo".  Assuming all stored ranges are narrow, this should be able to very quickly process partitions 1 and 2 by using that index to find zero possibly matching rows in them.

But really, you probably shouldn't be using partitioning for this at all.  You can index ranges directly by using a GiST index.  You could store ranges directly in the table, or you could use a functional index to index the ranges based on what you already have stored.  You have the extra complication of having the stored as floats when they shouldn't be, so that makes it extra fun.

```
create index on "IpLocationF" using gist (int8range("IpFrom"::bigint,"IpTo"::bigint,'[]'));
select * from "IpLocationF" where int8range("IpFrom"::int8,"IpTo"::int8,'[]') @> 1503395841::bigint limit 1;
```

Comment: Sure, different parameters will show different levels of luck. But I can confirm that both tables stores data with the same order. Because They are copies.

Comment: By the way I have created index with your code and tried range query, it is 1,5 times slower. with the same parameters. Here is something strange.

Comment: They can't be the same order.  Partitioning forces the orders to be different because they are segregated first by partition.

Comment: It is not surprising that the range query would be 1.5 times slower than the very lucky parameterization of the seq scan.  But it should be much faster than the average parameterization of it.